# Javascript detect resize won't work on mobile environment (Chrome Dev Tools)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a simple statement so that if a device size is less than 992px, it will disable a slider on the page.

When testing in the browser normally, it works perfectly and does what I want. When I switch to Chrome Dev Tools and try it out on a mobile environment, it doesn't work.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        $(".disable-owl-swipe").on("touchstart mousedown", function(e) {
    // Prevent carousel swipe
    e.stopPropagation();
});
  }
 else {
     //donothing
 }
});
```

Also I am also pretty sure that my comparison operator is wrong, (`$(window).width() > 992`)

Surely if I wanted an event to happen when a device is smaller than 992px it would be (`$(window).width() < 992`) - the weird thing is that it works perfectly.

Weird huh. Any thoughts?

Comment: `js` at Question appears to attach, reattach the `touchstart mousedown` to `".disable-owl-swipe"` at each `resize` event ?

Comment: I don't see what you're saying? Can you explain further

Comment: You're only firing an event on `resize` you should fire that event on `onload` too if you want that to work.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Don't know how I didn't spot it, thanks.

Comment: this also fixed my comparison operators problem